# Angular Material button change colour based on server response

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to change the colour of the button based on some conditions. But for some reason it is not getting applied.
My template code

```
<div class="button-wrap text-center">               
                    <button  mat-button class="mrgn-b-xs mrgn-r-xs" mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="startPrint(data.id)" 
                    [color]="job_status.get(data.id) == 'NEW' || 'START'? 'primary' : 'warn'" [disabled]="isDisabled">
                        <!-- <mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon> -->
                        {{job_status.get(data.id) | translate}}                    
                    </button> 
                    {{job_status.get(data.id)}}        
                </div>
```

My Component code

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("---- Inside PrintJobComponent ngOnInit()-----");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.pageTitleService.setTitle("Start Print Job");
    }, 0);

    this.coreService.getJobBoardContent().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.jobboardContent = response;
        console.log("Data: ", this.jobboardContent);
       
        this.jobboardContent.forEach(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.job_status.set(res.id,res.job_status);
            //this.changeButtonState(res.id);
        });

        console.log("this.job_status MAP object::: ", this.job_status);
        console.log("this.job_status for id: "+this.jobboardContent[0].id +" = "+ this.job_status.get(this.jobboardContent[0].id));
        
        this.startProgressBar(this.jobboardContent[0].id);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );    
  }
```

[image]

Comment: put () around the condition: ('NEW' || 'START')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying in wrong way the condition. Your condition is always true, because, 'START' always return true, since you do not compare with anything.

```
// false || true is always true.
job_status.get(data.id) == 'NEW' || 'START'? 'primary' : 'warn'"
```

Solution:

```
job_status.get(data.id) == 'NEW' || job_status.get(data.id) == 'START'? 'primary' : 'warn'"

// Or

"['NEW', 'START'].includes(job_status.get(data.id)) ? 'primary' : 'warn'"
```